# Are Lookup Filters supported in Custom Lightning Components?

Tags: bug, lookup-filter, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-base-component

So, there are two ways to get Salesorce Standard Lookup filed in Lightning components: force:inputField and lightning:inputField. However, no matter what I do, I can not get lookup filters to work. For example with lightning ns

```
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="DamageManagement__c">      
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Booking__c"  value="{!v.dm.Booking__c}" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Vehicle__c" value="{!v.dm.Vehicle__c}" />      
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

I have a filter on Vehicle to show only those for selected Booking. I enter the filter => no vehicles found. I remove the filter => vehicles found. In Lightning standard create page it works just fine as well as in classic. Same behavior with force:inputfield.

Is this supposed to work as I tried or am I missing something? Or this is not supported at all?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? It seems to be an issue to me.

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't find any solution that doesn't require writing or reusing some custom lookup component which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a known issue in Salesforce. 
Someone has posted an Idea here that we can vote on:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E9xzQAC